# How to update database table in android sqlite..?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Android.
I want to update the table data based on a CheckBox value.
But it's not updating the table - instead, I am getting a **No Such Table error**.

**Here is the code :**

```
  public class CheckListActivity extends Activity {

    CheckBox chkTask1, chkTask2, chkTask3, chkTask4, chkTask5, chkTask6,
            chkTask7, chkTask8, chkTask9, chkTask10;
    Button btnSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);

        chkTask1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task1_option);
        chkTask2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task2_option);
        chkTask3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task3_option);
        chkTask4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task4_option);
        chkTask5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task5_option);
        chkTask6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task6_option);
        chkTask7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task7_option);
        chkTask8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task8_option);
        chkTask9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task9_option);
        chkTask10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.task10_option);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String error = "";
                if (chkTask1.isChecked()) {
                    error = updateCheckList(1, 1);
                } else {
                    error = updateCheckList(0, 1);
                }

                if (chkTask2.isChecked()) {
                    error = updateCheckList(1, 2);
                } else {
                    error = updateCheckList(0, 2);
                }

                if (chkTask3.isChecked()) {
                    error = updateCheckList(1, 3);
                } else {
                    error = updateCheckList(0, 3);
                }

                if(error.length()>0){
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, "ERROR " +error,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, "Successfully Saved...!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
    }

    private String updateCheckList(int flag, int id) {

        String errorStr = "";

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("CheckList.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE CheckList SET CHECKEDFLAG = " + flag
                    + " WHERE ID = " + id;
            db.execSQL(sql);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorStr = errorStr + e.getMessage();
        }

        return errorStr;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Create your table first by using `SqlOpenHelper`

Comment: * Its straight forward that either "their is no table with that name" or "may be you might modified that table stuff ". If modified you need to clear data from app management in device setting and try again.

Comment: Is the table created yet? It seems that you lack code for creating the table, or at least it's not triggered before this code.

Comment: Yes table is created also have inserted data inside it........

Comment: Check your database name is same at both time i.e at the table creation time and updation time

Comment: If you are sure that you already have created and inserted data inside the table , uninstall and reinstall the app again. If not created yet and want to know how to create one , lemme know i can write an answer for that.

Comment: Hello, you can try if really your table exist, before "String sql...", try with create table if not exists tableName (col1 typ1, ..., colN typN), and try if you get same Exception.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks I uninstalled app and again run it work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: you added the table AFTER the app was run the first time.
Solution: You have to uninstall and reinstall your app.